# Splitting an array key and seeing if it contains a value

Tags: php

I have an array, I want to check if the keys have '-main' after them.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, -5) == '-main'){
        ....
    }
}
```

If they do have '-main' I then want to get the text prior to '-main'. I do:

```
$myVar = substr($key, 0, -5);
```

1. Is there a more efficient way of splitting the key so I don't have to do two sub strings?
2. Perhaps I do not want to use '-main' any more and want to use a different length search item, perhaps as a variable. I would then have to do a character count rather than specifying -5. Is there a way to incorporate a variable without having to do character counts?

Comment: Since your code works, I think a better place for this question would be over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Magnus Eriksson - added to code review, someone migrated back to SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105395/checking-if-an-array-key-contains-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways, but I think the easiest to test and capture would be:

```
$needle = '-main';

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/(.*)$needle\$/", $key, $match)){
        $myVar = $match[1];
    }
}
```

- Check for a match of `$needle` at the end of the string `$` and capture everything before it `(.*)`
- If found, assign the stuff from the first capture group `(.*)` to `$myVar`

You could also use `strstr()`, but would need to decide how to handle `$myVar` being false if `$needle` is not found:

```
if ($myVar = strstr($key, $needle, true)){
    ....
}
```

To find it anywhere in the `$key` and capture everything else:

```
if (strpos($key, $needle) !== false){
    $myVar = str_replace($needle, '', $key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would there also be a way to check for needle anywhere in the string? And assign $myVar to be the value of key without the $needle

Comment: Note that the `strpos` check is optional, which means *only one* string function is required to perform the check and capture. [See it on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EmN0V)