# Checking if an array key contains a value?

Tags: php

I have an array, I want to check if the keys have '-main' after them.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, -5) == '-main'){
        ....
    }
}
```

If they do have '-main' I then want to get the text prior to '-main'. I do:

```
$myVar = substr($key, 0, -5);
```

Is there a more efficient way of splitting the key so I don't have to do two sub strings?
Perhaps I do not want to use '-main' any more and want to use a different length search item, perhaps as a variable. I would then have to do a character count rather than specifying -5. Is there a way to incorporate a variable without having to do character counts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex search (http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) to do the task.

```
if (preg_match('/^(.*)(-main)$/', $key, $hit)) {
   $myVar = $hit[1];
   // explanation:
   // $hit[0] will contain the whole result string
   // $hit[1] will contain the part before "-main"
   // $hit[2] will be "-main"
}
```

The regular expression is the following:

- / ... / -> requiered by preg_match
- ^ -> beginning of string (we want to start at the first position
- (-main) -> the search text we're using
- $ -> end of the string (we don't want a -main in the middle of the string to match)
- (.*) anything else in the string between the start and "-main" - the paranthesis means, that this will be returned as one part of $hits

If you switch the text you want to search for, keep in mind that certain characters have a special meaning in a regex. So you might need to escape them.